# Projected Hold in Tennis

Tags: probability

I've been cracking my head on this one but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Senario:

Player A has a service hold of 83.1%
Player B has a service hold of 83.7%

Player A has a break percentage of 18,9%
Player B has a break percentage of 20,3%

The mean service hold for on this type of surface is 84,4%
But on the actual court they are playing the service hold is 1.5% lower that the avarage mean.

Service Hold is the avarage that the player who service in tennis wins the point

Break percentage is the avarage that the player who doesn't serve wins the point.

Question:
Based on these stats I want to know what the projected service hold will be of each player.
Any ideas?

Comment: For those of us not well-versed in tennis, it might be useful to define your terms "service hold," "break percentage," and why the "mean service hold" matters at all.

Comment: Hi, I've added an explination. I've included the mean service hold as the court they are playing at in this game is a slower than the average court. The slower a court is the more change their is that the player who service doesn't win the point. In this case 1.5% slower

Comment: It's not determined from the data.  Player $A$ might be exceptionally strong against $B$, or exceptionally weak, there's no way of telling...your numbers are, presumably, averages drawn from a large field of players.

Comment: @lulu yes, the data is drawn from a large field of players. lets asume that the players never played each other

Comment: It's a question of what you want your answer to mean.  Take the simple game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.  In a random match player A has an even chance of winning but,  of course, each specified  match is fully determined.    In your problem you could try to make an "intelligent guess"...B's numbers are slightly better than A's so it's not irrational to guess that B will lower A's numbers a bit.  There's really not enough information to try to use extra data like surface statistics (you didn't break the raw numbers down by surface type, for example).

Comment: Should say more generally:  in sport statistics, it's very difficult to disentangle individual probabilities from overall averages.  There are simply too many factors to take into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about tennis.

But you seem to be saying that based on past performance (1) A breaks 18.9% of his opponent's serves, and has 16.9% of his serves broken; (2) B breaks 20.3% of his opponent's serves, and has 16.3% of his serves broken; and (3) break percentages are 1.5% higher on this court.

So adjusting for the court we expect A to break 20.4% of B's serves, but we expect B to have 17.8% of his serves broken. Similarly we expect B to break 21.8% of A's serves, but we expect A to have 18.4% of his serves broken.

The question is how we come up with a projection which reconciles this data.

If we have no prior preferences and no other data, the best we can do is to take the mean, so we project A will have 20.1% of his serves broken, or a service hold of 79.1%, whilst we project B will have 19.1% of his serves broken, or a service hold of 80.9%.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Log5 formula developed by Bill James for projecting the probability team A beats team B given the win% of Team A & B.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log5

However, you need to use this derivation to account for league average break percentage: ExAvg = ((BAVG * PAVG) / LgAVG) / ((BAVG * PAVG) / LgAVG + ((1-BAVG)*(1-PAVG)/(1-LgAvg)))

https://www.fangraphs.com/tht/a-short-digression-into-log5/

So, accounting for the change in surface,

Player A will have a service hold of (83.1-1.5)% Player B has a service hold of (83.7-1.5)%, or 81.6% and 82.2%, respectively.

Player A has a break percentage of (18.9+1.5)% Player B has a break percentage of (20.3+1.5)%, or 20.4% and 21.8%, respectively.

So the probability player A breaks player B's serve is

((Abreak* Bhold) / LgAVG) / ((Abreak* Bhold) / LgAVG + ((1-Abreak)*(1-Bhold)/(1-LgAvg))) = 
((.204* .822) / .844) / ((.204* .822) / .844 + ((1-.204)*(1-.822)/(1-.844))) = 
(.2086 / (.2086 + (.796*.178/.156)) = .2086 / (.2086 + .9083) = .187 or 18.7%.

Answer (score 0):

An easier example is player (a) hold minus player (b) break plus ave break for tour.
You can expand on this further with the examples above of adding or subtracting the 1.5% to account for this court.